# Is there a way to call RStudio's code format programmatically?

Tags: r, rstudio, formatr

I'd like to pretty-format an R snippet. There's `formatR` but because it's based on `deparse` there's a lot it cannot actually do, pipe operator `%>%` being one of such things. RStudio has great code formatting capabilities but they don't seem to be accessible via any public API.

I checked that the actual code formatting algorithm is implemented in Java (seems to be?) and that there's a bunch of functions that RStudio exposes via `rstudioapi` (in C/C++ they seem to start with `rs_`). I wonder if there is a way to combine these observations into an R call that will execute code formatting procedure on the currently selected R snippet. I believe I could control the actual selection via the public `rstudioapi` API.

And if there's no *official* way, is there a hacky one?

Comment: I don't know if you can access RStudio's formatting, but take a look at the `styler` package https://github.com/r-lib/styler.  It seems to be extensible.

Comment: For a hacky solution:  once you have selected the section, get the OS to paste the "Reformat Code" keyboard shortcut into RStudio.  On a Mac, this is done by Automator.  I don't know about other systems...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `styler`!
I thought about sending the shortcut sequence via RStudio API (which isn't there, it seems) but not via the OS, that's an interesting path.

Comment: I've just found `rfmt` (https://github.com/google/rfmt), I think it will be exactly what I need. Also, here is an interesting summary of the current state of code formatting in R: https://github.com/rstats-gsoc/gsoc2017/wiki/Noninvasive-source-code-formatting